# Conversion from UTF-16 to ASCII in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a text that is in UTF-16 and i wish to convert the same into ASCII format.

> UTF-16: "고\u0094\u008C 援щℓ\u009C ы\u0096\u0089\u0094ν\u0092\u0088 \u0098\u008C利\u009D\u0095"

> expected result: "앰플 구매시 여행용 화장품 샘플증정"

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: added expected result i.e. in Korean language

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding with only 128 character that doesn't include characters from the Korean alphabet. You are probably looking for another encoding – do you know its name? If you don't the encoding's name, can you show the _bytes_ of the expected result?

Comment: BTW, your input looks somehow broken. Can you show its bytes too, please?